# What's the best free scriptable SFTP client for windows?

Tags: windows, sftp

What's the best free scriptable SFTP client for windows?

I've looked at WinSCP and FileZilla. WinSCP seems quite [buggy (click here)](http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?p=24476#24476), and FileZilla doesn't seem very scriptable.

Any suggestions?

Basically what I want to do is: from a scheduled task, log onto a remote server, pull any files across, and then delete them from the remote server.

Comment: Did you actually try WinSCP with your setup?

Comment: Yes i tried it, that bug that i mentioned is the result of me trying it.

Comment: I've fixed [that bug](http://winscp.net/tracker/show_bug.cgi?id=433) in WinSCP few days after you asked (what is over 6 years ago now).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the scp client that comes with putty pscp. You can use pscp on the command line like scp in a linux command line.

Comment: I just spent half an hour giving that a go. Got stuck on the prompt for the key fingerprint, couldn't find any way to make that prompt disappear in script.

Comment: that prompt should only appear the first time you connect to this machine

Comment: Actually, i got around that by piping in a one-line text file with 'n' as the only contents. It all works!

Comment: Note to others: I actually ended up using putty's PSFTP instead of PSCP.

Comment: so you were able to script PSFTP to login and download files as a remote task and not have to leave yourself logged in?

Answer (score 4):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). You can combine the power of command line [sftp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol) with the power of [BASH](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) scripting. All that, in Windows!

Comment: Cygwin is a pretty heavy install, isn't it? I was hoping for a one-exe solution, kinda like winscp portable exe. It would help smooth things over with the infra guys.

Comment: Yes. It's a heavy install indeed. I have solved basic scripting issues with WinSCP. But I don't know if it will be useful for very complex scripts. Haven't tried it.

Comment: @Chris yes - I refuse to use Cygwin because it is so heavy. There are many Unix-like tools that have been ported to Windows - they form part of the [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) collection for which I'm ever so thankful.

Comment: I really dislike Cygwin for this type of solution.  That's like saying "I know Linux but am forced to run on Windows, so I'll introduce a heavy dependency and new security threat vector so I don't have to learn anything new."  I know scripting and tool support on Windows was traditionally extremely poor and still has not caught up to Linux, but embrace the platform you are on.

Answer (score 3):

Putty scp has already been mentioned.

I want to mention putty psftp.exe which might be new.

Use the following command line:

psftp.exe  -l  -pw  -b

This will log into the ftp server and run *file-with-ftp-cmds* against it.

Full docs here:

http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.52/htmldoc/Chapter6.html

Comment: +1 this is actually what the OP stated he did in his comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out SecureFX by VanDyke.
http://www.vandyke.com/products/securefx/

or MKS Toolkit for Sys Admins
http://mkstoolkit.com/products/tk/ds_tkother.asp

Comment: They both look good, albiet not free...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, but take a look at
http://redpark.posterous.com/lftp-for-windows

From cygwin I am using only 3 files: bash.exe, ssh.exe and cygssp-0.dll.
Put them in the same directory as redpark's Windows port of lftp and go scripting.

Commandline example:

```
D:\lftp>bash
bash-4.1# export PATH=.
bash-4.1# lftp sftp://user:pass@somehost.com
lftp user@somehost.com:~> put -c cx160sd.flv
194749860 bytes transferred in 112 seconds (1.67M/s)
lftp user@somehost.com:/> exit
bash-4.1# exit
exit

D:\lftp>
```

It is no single exe solution, but uploads proved to be twice as fast as uploads by pscp.exe

Edit: new URL now posterious has stopped:
http://envelopepushing.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/lftp-for-windows/

Comment: i maintaine some windows build at http://nwgat.ninja/lftp-for-windows/ if anyone needs them

Comment: The lftp solution is still running in production, but looking around for new possibilities I grabbed Openssh portable and made it scriptable with Expect for Windows. Example: https://github.com/zetamatta/expect/issues/8#issuecomment-416445736

Answer (score 0):

Not free, but look at [edtFTPnet/PRO](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/overview.html) for a comprehensive script engine that supports SFTP on Windows.

Here's a sample script:

```
# Sample SFTP script 
set remotehost=edtmobile
set user=javaftp
set password=javaftp
set protocol=sftp
set localdir=D:\work\tmp

# connect to the server
open

# change dir
cd remote/test

# put the local file test.txt to the server as mytest.txt
put test.txt mytest.txt

# disconnect
close
```

Answer (score 0):

Note to others:
To create the scheduled task, simply open a text editor and write out the pscp command.  Then save the file as a .bat file.  Chapter 5 and 6 of the documentation have everything you'd ever want to know about how pscp works.

Note that pscp is quite particular about having a source and a target.  If you don't provide those, pscp will simply default back to the usage message.

Here's an example:

```
c:\pscp.exe -pw [your password] -batch -sftp someuser@example.com:/* c:\yourlocation
```

In this example pscp.exe is sitting in the root of th c directory.  -batch disables interactive prompts so that they won't interrupt the automated task. -sftp forces the sftp protocol, because in the question sftp is specified.  The :/* wildcard will bring back everything in the source, and the c:\yourlocation specifies where it ends up on your machine.

To schedule this as an automated task, simply bring up Scheduled Tasks.  In XP, this is in System Tools.  Then point the task to the .bat file you've created, give it a time to run, and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

Rush FTP; free, comes in portable versions and has a comprehensive scripting API (compatible with LUA language).

Answer (score 0):

If you work with powershell you can use something like netcmdlets (www.netcmdlets.com).  It is not a client per-se, but a set of libraries (cmdlets) for internet communications.  There is a free personal edition as well.  It's easy to configure schedules tasks to call powershell script and you have the benefit of being completely flexible/extensible through code.